# django using a link containing turkish characters

Tags: django, django-forms, ascii, domain-name, django-validation

I am creating django project. Django allow using turkish characters **(ş,ü,ö,İ,ğ,ı,ç)** in auth.User models. But I want to use usernames in links. For instance, **app.com/şüöİğıç.** There is no problem when I'm working some links (contain turkish characters)  on a computer. Is there any problem when ı publish project. I cant using slugify because one user can be 'şam' and one user can be 'sam'. So it can be conflict.
I want to create username validator for using just english letters. How can I do? 
Briefly, Is there any problem when using turkish letters on links(app.com/şüöİğıç) and if there is problem How can I solve this problem.

**forms.py:**

```
class registerForm(forms.ModelForm):
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ["email","first_name","last_name","password","username"]


    #model = ACCOUNTS
    #fields=['email','name','surname','username','password','birthday','gender','language']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3987 :

> This document defines a new protocol element, the Internationalized
> Resource Identifier (IRI), as a complement to the Uniform Resource
> Identifier (URI).  An IRI is a sequence of characters from the
> Universal Character Set (Unicode/ISO 10646).  A mapping from IRIs to
> URIs is defined, which means that IRIs can be used instead of URIs,
> where appropriate, to identify resources.

This explains how to generate proper URLs when you have character out of ASCII range.
For example:  http://www.w3.org/People/D%C3%BCrst/